# JPA error: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.<init>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I was mading a web app using JPA and last day I changed something that I don't remember and now I am getting this error in every page that I use JPA.

I don't remember exactly what I changed that made this error start, but was something to do with some libs. I don't know if I deleted a necessary lib or placed a bugged lib. I tried to reinstall another version of eclipse, reinstalled the glassfish, tried to create another project but all failed and the error still appears. I found nothing in the google, at least nothing that worked to me. Anyone can help me?

Here is my index.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <style>
body {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
</style>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css" />

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Controle de Mensalidade</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="alunos.xhtml">Alunos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="turmas.xhtml">Turmas</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <p:dataTable var="aluno" value="#{indexView.alunos}">
            <p:column headerText="Id">
                <h:outputText value="#{aluno.id}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Nome">
                <h:outputText value="#{aluno.nome}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Curso">
                <h:outputText value="#{aluno.turma.curso}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Ano">
                <h:outputText value="#{aluno.turma.ano}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

My index bean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import dao.ClassDAO;
import entities.Aluno;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class IndexView {
    ArrayList<Aluno> alunos;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ClassDAO<Aluno> alunosDAO = new ClassDAO<>(Aluno.class);
        alunos = alunosDAO.getAll();
    }

    public ArrayList<Aluno> getAlunos() {
        return alunos;
    }

    public void setAlunos(ArrayList<Aluno> alunos) {
        this.alunos = alunos;
    }
}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="mohr" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetectation" value="class" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/controle_mensalidade" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <!--  Configurações de Debug -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Finally, my ClassDAO:

```
public class ClassDAO<T> {
    static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    static EntityManager em;
    Class<T> typeClass;

    public ClassDAO(Class<T> typeClass){
        emf = null;
        em = null;
        this.typeClass = typeClass;
    }

    public static void abrirConexao() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mohr");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public T get(int id){
        abrirConexao();
        T t = em.find(typeClass, id);
        emf.close();
        return t;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> getAll(){
        abrirConexao();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        String classe = typeClass.getTypeName().substring(typeClass.getTypeName().lastIndexOf(".")+1);
        String hql = "select "  + classe.toLowerCase() + " from " + classe + " " + classe.toLowerCase();
        Query consulta = em.createQuery(hql);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> ts = consulta.getResultList();
        ArrayList<T> arrayT = new ArrayList<>(ts);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        emf.close();
        return arrayT;
    }

    public T getLast(){
        abrirConexao();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        String classe = typeClass.getTypeName().substring(typeClass.getTypeName().lastIndexOf(".")+1);
        String hql = "select "  + classe.toLowerCase() + " from " + classe + " " + classe.toLowerCase();
        Query consulta = em.createQuery(hql);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> ts = consulta.getResultList();
        ArrayList<T> arrayT = new ArrayList<>(ts);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        emf.close();
        return arrayT.get(arrayT.size()-1);
    }

    public void save(T t){
        abrirConexao();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.merge(t);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        emf.close();
    }

    public void remove(int id){
        abrirConexao();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(em.getReference(typeClass, id));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

The libs:

```
commons-codec-1.9
dom4j-1.6.1
eclipselink
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1
hibernate-core-5.0.0.Final
hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.0.Final
hibernate-envers-5.0.0.Final
hibernate-java8-5.0.0.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.0.0.Final
hibernate-osgi-5.0.0.Final
jandex-1.2.2.Final
javassist-3.18.1-GA
javax.faces-2.1.24
javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final
mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1
org.osgi.core-4.3.1
postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4
primefaces-5.2
black-tie-1.0.10
```

Comment: Can you show list of libs that you have included in your project?

Comment: @mateuszlo I added the libs in the end of the post. I don't know if all these libs are necessary but I am using this since last year and never had a problem before.